# Lightning Components: What is the easiest way to have an onclick event on a HTML-tag?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, html, event

In a Lightning Component I have

```
<div style="border: green solid 3px;" onclick="console.log(123);">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>       
</div>
```

As far as I see, the old-school events do not work. What is the easiest way to get a click-event on a div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inline Javascript is not supported due to security threat and you can simply use onclick event and always follow the [Unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) principles.You can look at document here which mentions to avoid [inline script](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security)

Try below code

```
 <div style="border: green solid 3px;" onclick="{!c.logData}">
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <br/>       
</div>
```

The controller code

```
({
   logData : function( cmp, evt,  h ){
     console.log(123);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the name of the event is `onclick` instead of `click`. I think you can bind your controller method to onclick by specifying a method.

Example:
`<div onclick='{!c.handle}' >Hello<div>`

Comment: I fixed that, thanks. But my real issue is addressed by @MohithSrivastava