# Creating hyperlinks in lightning community record tempaltes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, navigation, hyperlink

While testing different ways to provide clickable links to users, I realized that the standard documented approach doesn't seem to work and while attempting to customize a component to do the same, the onclick event did not seem to trigger my navigation method.

Example Custom Clickable link:

```
<div onclick="{!c.handleClick}" name="{!v.knowledgeRecord.Title}">{!v.knowledgeRecord.Title}</div>
```

The onclick event does not seem to work. My component is on the latest api version(44) Locker service does not seem to allow this based on past posts:

- [Lightning Component - Locker Service: Onclick button, div no longer working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128898/lightning-component-locker-service-onclick-button-div-no-longer-working)
- [Lightning Components: What is the easiest way to have an onclick event on a HTML-tag?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153520/lightning-components-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-an-onclick-event-on-a-html/153525)

If i check the documentation on anchor tags in lightning (
[Example Using Navigation Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm)) from the lightning developer Development guide, the suggested approach would seem to be:

```
<a onclick="{!c.handleClick}">{!v.knowledgeRecord.Title}</a>
```

Again, this method does not seem to trigger my navigation method, eventhoug the doc states:

> Use Navigation Events
>   Use one of the navigation events for consistent behavior across Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

However, If I use a `lightning:formattedUrl` component, I am able to  specify a value, label and so on, and onclick it seems to redirect accordingly,

```
<lightning:formattedUrl label="{!v.knowledgeRecord.Title}" 
                                           target="_blank" value="{! $Site.siteUrlPrefix + '/article/' + v.knowledgeRecord.Id}" />
```

Is the later the best approach? or am I doing something wrong when attempting to use the anchor tag (eventhough it is literally copy pasted from the documetnation).